# Amazon Redshift : Acces Denied RestoreClusterSnapshotRequest

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-sdk

I have having trouble when i try to Restore cluster with Snapshot. I would appreciate any pointers.

The code using is :

```
var con = new AmazonRedshiftClient(acess_key_id, secret_acess_key, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2);

        var restore = new Amazon.Redshift.Model.RestoreFromClusterSnapshotRequest()
        {
            ClusterIdentifier = clusterIdentifier,
            SnapshotIdentifier = snapshotIdentifier,
            AvailabilityZone = "us-west-2a",
        };

        var response = con.RestoreFromClusterSnapshot(restore);

        Console.WriteLine("Cluster Status : {0}", response.Cluster.ClusterStatus);
```

When it 's calling the RestoreClusterSnapshotRequest operation, I have an exception :
 "Access Denied. Please ensure that your IAM Permissions allow this operation."

Using Identity-Based Policies (IAM Policies) for Amazon Redshift like this
Policy :

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "redshift:CopyClusterSnapshot",
            "redshift:RestoreFromClusterSnapshot",
            "redshift:AuthorizeSnapshotAccess",
            "redshift:RevokeSnapshotAccess"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:redshift:us-west-2:{AccoundId}:*/backup-20160208-dbrd",
            "arn:aws:redshift:us-west-2: {AccoundId}:cluster:*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "redshift:DescribeClusterSnapshots"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Could any one help me to overcome this issue.. and please correct me if i done any mistake in thease process.. .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43636147/296829), you should change this line:

```
"arn:aws:redshift:us-west-2:{AccoundId}:*/backup-20160208-dbrd",
```

to

```
"arn:aws:redshift:us-west-2:{AccoundId}:snapshot:*/backup-20160208-dbrd",
```

Also, I found with a bunch of trial and error and help from AWS support that you will also need several `ec2` permissions to restore a Redshift cluster from a snapshot. The list at this time is:

```
    {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
            "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
            "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
            "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
            "ec2:DescribeInternetGateways"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
```

You may just want to do `ec2:Describe*` for convenience and/or to prevent this breaking in the future if the exact set of permissions changes.

The [Amazon Redshift Snapshots docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-snapshots.html) (search for "RestoreFromClusterSnapshot") should be updated soon with this information.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the snapshot details section in the "resource" segment.
    Please see below the updated one:

```
"Resource": [
            "arn:aws:redshift:us-west-2:{AccoundId}:*/backup-20160208-dbrd",
            "arn:aws:redshift:us-west-2: {AccoundId}:cluster:*",
            "arn:aws:redshift:us-west-2:{AccoundId}:snapshot:*"
        ]
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Crazy but that is this is the secret sauce.

```
        "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
        "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
        "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
        "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
        "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
        "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
        "ec2:DescribeInternetGateways"
```