# EC2 IAM policy permissions for creating a redshift cluster from a snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create a cluster from a snapshot via the cli in an EC2:

```
aws redshift restore-from-cluster-snapshot --cluster-identifier <myNewCluster>  --snapshot-identifier snapshotID
```

And I'm getting the error:

```
An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the RestoreFromClusterSnapshot operation: Access Denied. Please ensure that your IAM Permissions allow this operation.
```

In the EC2 role, I'm using a policy with this settings:
Policy open to all redshift resources:

```
    "Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "s3:*",
            "redshift:*",
            "logs:*",
            "iam:*",
            "ec2:*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Sid": ""
    }
```

The role has also a boundary that includes these permissions:

```
 {   "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "redshift:Describe*",
                "redshift:List*",
                "redshift:View*",
                "redshift:Accept*",
                "redshift:Cancel*",
                "redshift:Create*",
                "redshift:*Tags",
                "redshift:ModifyClusterM*",
                "redshift:ModifySa*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "redshift:RestoreFromClusterSnapshot"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:redshift:us-west-1:123456789012:cluster:*",
                "arn:aws:redshift:us-west-1:123456789012:snapshot:*/*"
            ]
        }
```

These are all within the same account. Describe, Delete etc. works fine but creating a cluster from snapshot fails with the above error.
I checked this answer[adding IAM permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71219379/iam-permissions-to-create-a-new-redshift-cluster-from-another-clusters-snapshot) but I'm still getting the error I'm using an EC2 instead of a user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IAM permissions to create a new Redshift cluster from another cluster's snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71219379/iam-permissions-to-create-a-new-redshift-cluster-from-another-clusters-snapshot)

Comment: Is the snapshot e.g. encrypted with a KMS key?

Comment: I tried to add all ec2 permissions (see updated statement) like stated in the other answer, but I'm still getting the error. The snapshot is not encrypted. Using a local admin role I can run the command and create the cluster, but not from the ec2.

Comment: Can you show your role's trust relationships?

Comment: Trusted relationship:             "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "redshift.amazonaws.com",
                    "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are blocking yourself with the permissions boundary.

As per the AWS documentation: ["A permissions boundary is an advanced feature for using a managed policy to set the maximum permissions that an identity-based policy can grant to an IAM entity"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html). Meaning that it does NOT grant any permissions by itself but instead creates a threshold for a given IAM Role or IAM user.

In your case, you can do one of the below to be able to [restore a Redshift cluster from a snapshot from your EC2 instance using AWS CLI](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/redshift/restore-from-cluster-snapshot.html):

**a) remove the permissions boundary altogether**

This solution is the easiest, quickest, and maybe enough to accomplish your current needs. Nonetheless, this is also the least secure one. It leaves your EC2 with a very permissive role - not something recommended in a production environment as it does not adhere to [the principle of least privilege](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/techniques-for-writing-least-privilege-iam-policies/).

**b) update the permissions boundary with the missing EC2 actions**

Your permissions boundary misses a few EC2-related actions. If you update it to the following, it'll work:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
                "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeInternetGateways",
                "redshift:Describe*",
                "redshift:List*",
                "redshift:View*",
                "redshift:Accept*",
                "redshift:Cancel*",
                "redshift:Create*",
                "redshift:*Tags",
                "redshift:ModifyClusterM*",
                "redshift:ModifySa*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "redshift:RestoreFromClusterSnapshot"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:redshift:us-west-1:123456789012:cluster:*",
                "arn:aws:redshift:us-west-1:123456789012:snapshot:*/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

(I took the missing permissions from the AWS-managed *AmazonRedshiftFullAccess* policy and validated your use-case with and without them.)

**c) remove the permissions boundary and tighten up the IAM role**

If the use of permissions boundaries is not a hard requirement, you can remove the permissions boundary from your EC2 role and swap the current role's permissions for the ones I listed in point **b)**.

Comment: Thanks, adding these ec2 to the permission boundary worked.  Unfortunately I can't remove the boundary due to restrictions.